# Need some help for top label

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I need some suggestion to get a similar text line on top of this Excel Chart image.

[image: Example Excel Chart]

To positioning chars '[', 'BL' and ']' I am using the following piece of Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def make_y_array(value, x):
    return [value] * len(x)


def top_label(plt, ax, xstart, xend, y, text):
    start = ax.text(xstart, y, "[", fontsize=7, verticalalignment="center", horizontalalignment="left", )
    
    midpoint = (xstart + xend) / 2
    ax.text(midpoint, y, text, fontsize=7, verticalalignment="center", horizontalalignment="center", )
    end = ax.text(xend, y, "]", fontsize=7, verticalalignment="center", horizontalalignment="right", )

Fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# create data
maximum_x_elements = 30
maximum_y_elements = 5

color = "g"
mark = "o"  # , 'D', 'v','s'
y1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
ylabels = ["", "rsa", "mah", "boh"]
ax.set_yticks(y1)
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels, minor=False)

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 15, 28]
y = make_y_array(1, x)
plt.plot(x, y, color=color, marker=mark, markerfacecolor="None", markeredgecolor=color, linestyle="None", )

x = [5, 6, 8, 9]
y = make_y_array(1, x)

plt.plot(x, y, color=color, marker=mark, markerfacecolor=color, markeredgecolor=color, linestyle="None", )


top_label(plt, ax, 0.2, 5, maximum_y_elements * 1.02, "BL")
top_label(plt, ax, 5.2, 8, maximum_y_elements * 1.02, "CAB1")
top_label(plt, ax, 10, 20, maximum_y_elements * 1.02, "UFF")

ax.set_xlim(0, maximum_x_elements)
ax.set_ylim(0, maximum_y_elements)

plt.show()
```

Resulting in this image:

[image: top_label() result]

But I would like find some line of code to get something similar to
'[--BL--]' defining the distance from [ and ].
or underlined BL, ar a bottom-bordered bar with BL inside.
Any idea?

Comment: `'BL'.center(10, '-') → '----BL----'`

Comment: This would be useful if I knew how many characters I will need, but what I need is a length of 5, 7, 10 in terms of chart scale. In the above example '] [' must be at chart unit 5.

Comment: I know there are axes transform methods, but I didn’t find anything clear cut. Perhaps transforming the xstart and xend to pixel scale, get the pixel space between them, determine the pixel width of a character, and divide.